# Clean way to log response from debugQuery in SolrNet

Tags: c#, .net, solr, solrnet

We have added a property that let us add `debugQuery=true` as option when querying Solr from our application. Sometimes the queries can be complex, so we need to see what parts of the query takes time. However I have not been able to find any good way to get the response from Solr without using `ISolrConnection.Get()` and build up the query manualy (and getting the raw XML). Today we do like this:

```
var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<SolrDocument>>();
var qo = new QueryOptions();
        qo.AddFilterQueries(AuthorizationIncludeQuery(solrQueryParameter.AccessibleDocuments));
        qo.AddFilterQueries(new SolrQuery("person_id:" + solrQueryParameter.PersonId));
        qo.Start = solrQueryParameter.Start;
        qo.Rows = solrQueryParameter.Rows;
        qo.Fields = new[] { "*", "score" };


if (Constants.SolrDebugEnabled)
{
      var debugParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("debugQuery", "true") };
      qo.ExtraParams = debugParams;
}
try
{
   return solr.Query(searchQuery, qo);
}
```

Since we use `ISolrOperations<T>` and return `SolrQueryResults<T>` The extra parameters gets "lost" in the process. Any way to read out the extra parameters without too much rewriting?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/solrnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at the `SolrQueryExecuter` class on [GitHub](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/ee56b02c913a9b52459cefe1cc1623cc254d5f3b/SolrNet/Impl/SolrQueryExecuter.cs#L540)

gave me the answer. I basicly implemented the `Execute` method in my code:

```
private static SolrQueryResults<SolrConsistencyCheckDocument> FindAllDocumentsWithDebugEnabled(string searchQuery, QueryOptions qo)
{
        var directConnection = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrConnection>();
        var queryResult = new SolrQueryResults<SolrConsistencyCheckDocument>();
        var debugParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("debugQuery", "true") };
        qo.ExtraParams = debugParams;
        var parser = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrAbstractResponseParser<SolrConsistencyCheckDocument>>();
        var solrQueryTest = new SolrQueryExecuter<SolrConsistencyCheckDocument>(
            parser,
            directConnection,
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrQuerySerializer>(),
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrFacetQuerySerializer>(),
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrMoreLikeThisHandlerQueryResultsParser<SolrConsistencyCheckDocument>>());
        var parameters = solrQueryTest.GetAllParameters(new SolrQuery(searchQuery), qo);
        var resultq = directConnection.Get(solrQueryTest.Handler, parameters);
        var responseXML = XDocument.Parse(resultq);
        LogDebugElement(responseXML);
        parser.Parse(responseXML, queryResult);
        return queryResult;
    }
```